# Java and Golang http performance compare

Tags: java, go

I recently started using golang, and I did a test to compare the performance of java and golang http calls; I was surprised to find that golang is much faster than java, and sometimes it takes almost no time to call another service from one service. I am curious that this is due to the nature of the language or is the java framework doing too much to make it slower?

JAVA environment:

JDK1.8

Springboot2.1.7.RELEASE

Golang environment:

go1.9.3

## JAVA service1(LISTEN 10006 PORT):

```
        @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(String name) {
        log.info("in");
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:10007/hello?name=" + name, String.class);
        log.info("out");
        return result;
    }
```

## JAVA service2(LISTEN 10007 PORT):

```
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(String name) {
        log.info("in");
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
```

## Golang service1(LISTEN 10008 PORT):

```
        func main() {
           fmt.Println("start")
           http.HandleFunc("/hello", DefaultHandler)
           err := http.ListenAndServe(":10008", nil)
           if err != nil {
            fmt.Errorf("error: %s", err)
           }
        }
        func DefaultHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
           name := r.FormValue("name")
           fmt.Printf("%s, %s\r\n", time.Now(), "in")
           resp, _ := http.Get("http://localhost:10009/hello?name=" + name)
           body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
           defer resp.Body.Close()
           fmt.Printf("%s, %s\r\n", time.Now(), "out")
           w.Write(body)
}
```

## Golang service2(LISTEN 10009 PORT):

```
        func main() {
           fmt.Println("start")
           http.HandleFunc("/hello", DefaultHandler)
           err := http.ListenAndServe(":10009", nil)
           if err != nil {
             fmt.Errorf("error: %s", err)
           }
        }
        func DefaultHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
           fmt.Printf("%s, %s\r\n", time.Now(), "in")
           name := r.FormValue("name")
           w.Write([]byte("Hello " + name))
        }
```

I used browser to send request like this:

http://localhost:10006/hello?name=tom

http://localhost:10008/hello?name=tom

The result is mostly like the following

JAVA service1：

2019-10-21 22:04:46.406  INFO 16936 --- [ XNIO-1 task-12] com.web.test6.controller.TestCtrl        : in

2019-10-21 22:04:46.412  INFO 16936 --- [ XNIO-1 task-12] com.web.test6.controller.TestCtrl        : out

JAVA service2：

2019-10-21 22:04:46.410  INFO 16200 --- [  XNIO-1 task-6] com.web.test7.controller.TestCtrl        : in

Golang service1:

2019-10-21 22:06:36.1888823 +0800 CST m=+1438.272728801, in

2019-10-21 22:06:36.1888823 +0800 CST m=+1438.272728801, out

Golang service2:

2019-10-21 22:06:36.1888823 +0800 CST m=+1436.497480201, in

Comment: It could be any number of factors, from the implementation, to the runtime, to the context of the benchmark (for example, cold boot performance is often a problem for Java applications). "Why is program A faster than program B" is going to be far too broad a question to answer here.

Comment: it probably does not matter here, but consider that java 8 is years older than go 1.9.3

Comment: Closed but I can add some few directions here. If you are curious how to find out:

1. Try profiling and visualise the flame graph of your java and golang calls. Which component and program calls they spent most time at? Often, issuance of mem allocation syscall can impede performance. 

2. Also, notice how golang http framework does optimisation to have a go-routine pool handling the connection. Does Spring boot have this strategy?

Overall, it might not be (or might be) language difference. But often, they way they implement optimisation like network buffer management can be the edge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, you are comparing:

> Springboot2.1.7.RELEASE

against:

> Golang environment: go1.9.3

And your Go code puts up a minimalistic HTTP service. Whereas your Java solution seems to go with a "full fledged" Spring boot instance.

Which is like: comparing a single apple against a *truckload* of melons.

In other words: in order to get to meaningful numbers, you should compare "about equal" context. Spring boot is "much" more than a simple HTTP server (well, unless you strip it down to just be that).

Meaning: I would suggest to not go with Spring boot, but the most "minimalistic" http server/framework you can find for java.

Comment: So the answer is close to the JAVA framework doing too much in this case

Comment: @xupy Frameworks do what they are designed for. When *you* decide to compare a pickup truck against a sportscar, then *you* shouldn't be surprised that the sportscar is faster. But that one  can transport 20 or 30 times more "stuff" using the pickup truck.

Comment: [Endpoint](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html) and [Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/ws/Provider.html) are probably the simplest way to implement a barebones web service.

Comment: My opinion, with the logic that a Springboot do "extraneous" thing as an excuse for slower speed in a "Hello world" http server benchmark. This simply means it has a bad framework design. Yes, with full-fledge batteries in Spring, we loaded a "truck of melons" to the memory stack. But a good library / framework, full-fledge or minimalistic, should avoid invoking these unecessary "extraneous" thing when we simply just want a http server.

Comment: Thus, the analogy for sport car vs truck of melons here doesn't make sense. What does it even mean in the context of http benchmark? Sport car -> light weight request? Truck -> heavy and slow, but can carry heavy batch throughput of data? Definitely not a good analogy.